Finding the approximate number of primes possible for prime power composite number
I have number $n$ which is prime power, i.e $n = p^{k}$. I'm trying to to find all possible primes whose prime power can be in that range of $n$.
For example if $n$ is 2048 bit number then the possible prime powers fall in that range are as follows:

$p^{2}$ where p is a $2048/2$ bit prime

$p^{3}$ where p is a $2048/3$ bit prime
...

$p^{64}$ where p is a $2048/64$ bit prime


On the lower side my interest is upto calculating 64 bit prime powers.
From the wiki, i learnt the prime counting formula = $n/log\ n$
Based on which if i extrapolate the formula to find the count of number, lets say $x$
$x = n^{1/2}/log\ n^{1/2} - ((n^{1/2}-1)/log\ (n^{1/2}-1)) + n^{1/3}/log\ n^{1/3} - ((n^{1/3}-1)/log\ (n^{1/3}-1)) + ... + n^{1/64}/log\ n^{1/64} - ((n^{1/64}-1)/log\ (n^{1/64}-1))$
My question how can i solve this expression of $x$ into more simple formula so that I can extend this to even higher bits of numbers or is there a better way i can find primes whose prime powers fall into a given specific bit prime power number.

"range of $n$" is very confusing. A range must have a lower and an upper bound. If those are given , you can , for every exponent , find the bounds for $p$.

"n is 2048 bit number" : please clarify what this signifies.

n is exactly a 2048 bit number.

"n is exactly a 2048 bit number" : Does this mean that $~2^{2047} \leq n < 2^{2048} ~?$

@user2661923 right, $n$ is in that range you mentioned.

$2^{2047} > 10^{600}.~$  For a specific value of $~k,~$ you would have to investigate primes less than $~10^{600/k}.~$ What is the source of this problem, and what is the intent of the problem composer?

In NIST 800-89 , 5.3.3 for partial public key validation of RSA, the condition is that the modulus can't be prime power. So while exploring that problem out of curiosity i thought of figuring out how many such numbers exists in $||n||$ bit space which are of prime powers. So in figuring out that approximate number I ended up with this question.
